# Routing tasks to specific modules in GAE devserver

Tags: java, google-app-engine, module, task-queue, devserver

I'm trying to convert my current GAE project to using modules. I'd like all tasks of a certain path to run on a specific module.

I understand that in production, I can just enqueue the task as normal and the dispatch file handles routing it to the correct module.

However, how can I get this same behaviour in the dev server? I'd rather not do something hackey like addressing the module directly.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there anything in the "Routing Requests to Modules" docs that is not working for you? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/routing

Comment: No - that stuff works as documented. Just wondering how other people do it. If I have to manage a dispatch file thats used in prod to route tasks but then also address the modules directly when enqueuing tasks - its seems hard to manage because there are two places where these paths exist.

Comment: In that case, I don't know a way to do it directly. If you just want to avoid having that duplicated info, you could enqueue all tasks through a dedicated module which actually has all urls declared and just dispatchs to the desired one, but I think that's an overkill.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using path routing to get your tasks to run on specific modules, you could create a queue for each module with the correct [target parameter](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/queue#target). Any task that you send to this queue will be executed against that module. You could even create a separate queue for each class of task.